# How do I prevent this form data from repopulating?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-wtforms

I just finished making a simple number guessing webgame that tells the user whether their number is higher or lower than the solution.

When submitting data to the webpage, the page updates properly with the game data, except that the text input field is filled in with data that was just previously submitted. It's annoying having to delete the text in the field before making another guess, I'd much prefer if it rendered the template with an empty form field.

I was able to solve this issue in the past by using redirect instead of render_template, but I need render_template in this case to pass data to the page.

Also, any general suggestions on my design would be appreciated, I'm quite new at this.

Here is the page function:

```
@app.route('/numbers', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def numbers():
    x = open(os.path.join(basedir, 'textdata/nums.txt'), 'r')
    numdata = x.readlines()
    solved = True if numdata[0] == 'Solved\n' else False
    tries = int(numdata[1][:-1])
    answer = int(numdata[2])
    x.close()
    form = NumForm()
    newform = NewNumForm()
    if newform.validate_on_submit() and request.form['btn'] == 'New Game':
        randnum = randint(1, 100)
        x = open(os.path.join(basedir, 'textdata/nums.txt'), 'w')
        x.write('Unsolved\n0\n' + str(randnum))
        x.close()
        return redirect('/numbers')
    if form.validate_on_submit() and request.form['btn'] == 'Submit':
        num = form.num.data
        if num not in [str(i) for i in range(1, 101)]:
            return render_template('numbers.html', form=form, ttl='Numbers',
                                   tries = tries, wrongin = True)
        tries += 1
        if int(num) == answer:
            x = open(os.path.join(basedir, 'textdata/nums.txt'), 'w')
            x.write('Solved\n' + str(tries) + '\n' + str(answer))
            x.close()
            return render_template('numend.html', form=newform, ttl='Numbers',
                                   tries = tries, justsolved = True,
                                   answer = answer)
        if int(num) > answer:
            greater = False
        if int(num) < answer:
            greater = True
        x = open(os.path.join(basedir, 'textdata/nums.txt'), 'w')
        x.write('Unsolved\n' + str(tries) + '\n' + str(answer))
        x.close()
        return render_template('numbers.html', form=form, ttl='Numbers',
                               tries = tries, greater = greater, num = num)

    if solved:
        return render_template('numend.html', form=newform, ttl='Numbers',
                               tries = tries, answer = answer)
    return render_template('numbers.html', form=form, ttl='Numbers',
                           tries = tries)
class NumForm(Form):
    num = StringField('num')

class NewNumForm(Form):
    pass
```

And the page template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <br>
    <br><form action="" method="post" name="numform">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {% if num %}
            {% if greater %}
            The number is greater than {{ num }}
            {% else %}
            The number is smaller than {{ num }}
            {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            <h2>Guess the number! (between 1 and 100)</h2>
            <br>
            {{ form.num(size='3', autofocus=true) }}
            <br>
            {% for error in form.num.errors %}
                <span>[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}<br>
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="btn"></p>
        {% if wrongin %}
            <span>Whole numbers 1-100 only</span>
            <br>
        {% endif %}
        Tries: {{ tries }}
    </form>
    <br>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to continue using `render_template` as you have been, a simple fix would be to add this line:

```
    form.num.data = None
```

Just before your call to `render_template`. This will remove the data in the form for that particular field.

For a real application, the best practice would be to redirect immediately following the form submission, so that the user cannot click the Refresh button on the browser and accidentally re-submit the form. If you need to pass data between redirects, you could look in to Flash messages or even use the Session to store data.